Two queries with the same field name on one graph - how can I distinguish them?
I want to monitor a number of queues on one graph panel. I have records in a combined Elastic index, where each record gives the name of the queue and the current list of durations for the items.
I have Grafana showing percentiles for my build queues, and I can put them together on the same axes.
The trouble is that since they only differ in the query string - selecting this or that set of records by the 'name' field - the legend at the bottom is based off the same 'queue' field for both of the queries:
- p25.0 queue - p50.0 queue - p75.0 queue - p95.0 queue - p99.0 queue - p25.0 queue - p50.0 queue - p75.0 queue - p95.0 queue - p99.0 queue

I'd like to see
- p25.0 Android - p50.0 Android - p75.0 Android - p95.0 Android - p99.0 Android - p25.0 iOS - p50.0 iOS - p75.0 iOS - p95.0 iOS - p99.0 iOS

I've tried an 'override' for 'Display name', but that just makes all the percentiles for that query read the same without the 'p25' stuff. (I tried adding $1 or * in case that turned into p50)
I've tried a transform, in the hope I could regex 'queue' to 'Android', and then specify 'Android' as my field name, but not only did that not work, I realise it would have applied to all the queries anyway.

Is there a way to change the percentiles' base name on a per query way?

